# Paypal Sandbox payment pending status

Tags: paypal-sandbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [paypall IPN always return “payment_status: Pending” on sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298117/paypall-ipn-always-return-payment-status-pending-on-sandbox)

I want to test my transaction system with the Paypal Sandbox, but whenever I do a test transaction, the status of the payment is always "Pending".

I have set "Payment Review" to "Disabled" on both the selling and buying account as well as tried with and without "Negative Test Mode" enabled.

Also the sandbox manual says that there should be an option to clear payments manually after logging in as the buyer account, this appears not to be true.

More details:
"PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON" is always set to "authorization"
Both accounts are in GBP and I have tried transferring GBP and USD, nothing works

Someone out there must have got it to work, what is my problem?

Comment: I resolved this one myself. I think not being able to turn off "pending" is a "feature" of paypal express checkout, since maybe paypal assumes that the account holder would have to review each payment and ship something (although what I am "selling" is a virtual product).
Anyway I switched to "Adaptive payments" where the "pending" switch works.