# sandbox paypal Webhooks event for PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is always PENDING

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I am using a paypal subscription button, with server side listener for webhook event notifications still in sandbox mode.

I think everything is fine for every event except for `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`. Here I receive the event notification, verify, process and respond with a small html page (some regular description page) with http status `200`. When I go back to the paypal developer dashboard I see the event still being `PENDING`. The exact same event is not being resend, as it would be the case if i would have responded with any other http status code than `2xx`.

What is the reason for this `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` event always being `PENDING`. Do I have to take some additional action for this event?

Comment: Your sandbox account have a option to `review payment`, disable this and then check, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298117/paypal-ipn-always-return-payment-status-pending-on-sandbox

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have already switched back to make the api calls by hand on the server and that works for me (no PENDING).